# Get element that the mouse is hover on without moving mouse - jQuery JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application that contains several transitioning elements. These same elements react to mouseenter and mouseleave events. These events are deactivated during transitions to avoid users interacting with elements in transit.

The problem comes in when one of these elements are underneath the mouse when they are made active again. Once the moving elements are no longer moving, they should again register that the mouse is hovering on top of them. But since the mouseenter took place whilst the element was deactivated, the event is not fired once the element is made active once more.

If you then move your mouse off of the element, and then on again, it works fine. This is obviously not very user friendly.

Is there a way to register that the mouse is hovering on an element without moving the mouse?

More information on the elements discussed above:
The elements in question are large divs that contain a lot of content. They are actually pages in the application that I add and remove dynamically. I have a custom scroll bar that shows if the area has focus, and hides if it does not.

As the mouse moves into the page content area, the custom scroll bar shows. Once it moves out, the scroll bars hide again. All events are made inactive whilst the animation is running.

The problem is that is the mouse moves into the page area whilst a page is animating, the the scroll bars do not (and should not) show. Once the animation completes, however, the application should register that the user is hovering inside of the page area without him moving the mouse outside and back inside this space.

Comment: Did you try using .trigger() of jQuery

Comment: @Ashirvad: How do you mean? That might help me trigger the event, but I still need to check if the mouse is over the element before triggering it.

Comment: I would suggest trying to remove any hover functionality from your app, as with more and more tablets and touch devices, there are more and more devices that don't support hovering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Track the position of the mouse using a `mousemove` event, and test the element at the last known mouse position when you re-enable the behaviour using

```
document.elementFromPoint(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do not want to do a 'mousemove' however, since I am really looking speciffically for a way to do this without the user having to move a mouse. I have also been reading about 'elementFromPoint', and the browser comparability looks a bit sketchy. None the less, I'll give it a quick bash and let you know what I manage.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I actually got it working :) I fired the command at the end of the transition instead of on a mouse move, and it works great. I still need to do some browser testing, but is seems to be working so far. Thanks again.

Comment: Tested in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE8 and 9. Works great :)

Comment: Glad you got it working. The purpose of the mousemove as I suggested is to simply track the mouse on the page and not to trigger the test. It's just a method for tracking the mouse and reading the position when you need it, when it is normally only available on a mouse-initiated event. How did you read the position of the mouse?

Comment: I do actually use mousemove to obtain the coordinates. I think I misunderstood what you were saying, but did what you suggested anyway :) Thanks again